How to add remote ActiveMQ connection to Wildfly 31.0.1Final?
I’m migrating from WildFly 18.0.0.Final to 31.0.0.Final, but I need to configure my ActiveMQ remote connections and queues. I haven’t been able to find any useful documentation on this.
Currently, we use the ActiveMQ resource adapter (activemq-ra.rar) for connectivity in WildFly 18.
Wildfly 31 standalone-full.xml on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/W1LPCSpy https://pastebin.com/W1LPCSpy
Resource-adapter from Wildfly 18.0.0.0 final:
https://pastebin.com/b8bGKDb9 code
When i try to use the resource-adapters from the old standalone-full.xml file i got errors.

Which version of the resource adapter are you using ? You need a JakartaEE 10 compliant rar
